# is it possible to change or to wrap the exception when using Validate.notNull()

Tags: java, apache-commons

I am talking about the Validate 
API in apache commons lang, I do not see anything in the [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/Validate.html#notNull(T))

I know the the following is possible

```
try { Validate.notNull(object) } catch (NullPointerException ex) { throw MyCustomException(ex) }
```

but I was looking for something more simple then the whole try/catch block.

Comment: Looking at the source of the method, it looks like you can enter a custom message, but not the type of the exception. You can also use the overloaded method to specify values for your message. `public static <T> T notNull(T object,                           String message, Object... values)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can write something like that:

```java
Validate.notNull(data, "Data cannot be null");
```

But you will be getting only NullPointerException with your message. This have been described here (at the top of article): http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/Validate.html

> An invalid null argument causes a NullPointerException.

There is no more simpler way.

2. Or you can use Optional. e.g.:

```java
        Optional<UserEntity> userOptional = userService.findByUsername(username);
        userOptional.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with username " + username));
```

Comment: I was intending to change the exception type ( my custom type), not the message, the optional vs the try/catch, I think try /catch is more universal. trying to do it with the apache commons API

Comment: As I mention in my answer: There is no more simpler way, than the way you have described in your question (if you are using Validate.notNull).

Answer (score 1):

after some time of research we can conclude It is not possible.